# Where can I get photoshop images like this for my website

Tags: images, photoshop

I see a lot of websites [like this one](http://www.onechosen.org/default.asp) and I wanted to see where people get these images from to have the raised panel floating on the background. I see a lot of these sites use this technique and i wonder how they do this . .

[image]

Do these sites build this stuff in photoshop from scratch or is there a place to get templates like this to use on a website?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is easy to do in Photoshop. Plenty of [tutorials](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2291-Three-Quick-Drop-Shadow-Techniques-in-Adobe-Photoshop) around.

Most people build simple things like this from scratch. Free stock photos such as the paper texture background can be found at: http://www.sxc.hu/ or http://www.stockvault.net

There are some free website templates like at http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/ if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a graphic artist but I work with several of them. For an experienced graphic artist this is fairly easy to do. It looks like they just made everything but the heading ("Our mission") and copy a background image and placed the text over it in a `<DIV>`. It probably would be a handful of layers:

- one for the "paper"
- one for the heading-background
- one for the heading text
- one for the photo
- one for the signature

I don't know of there being a template out there for this but this is simple enough that there could be one. Maybe someone will know about it and link to it here.

Comment: In fact they've just done it as one image: http://www.onechosen.org/images/v2/welcome_box.png

Comment: Whomever downvoted this care to explain why?

Comment: Don't know who did, I did a +1.